# how to save credentials to keychain swift

Tags: swift, keychain

I want give my users the option to save their email and password to apple's keychain and it does not seem to be working

This is my function to add the SecItem to the keychain but there is nothing there when I check my keychain after calling this function on my device event when passing in hardcoded strings

```
func saveCredentialsToKeychain(username: String, password: String) throws {
    let account = username
    let password = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    var query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                            kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
                            kSecValueData as String: password]
    let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError(status: status) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usualy use this `query` with a `kSecAttrService`, works for me:

```
 let query: [CFString: Any] = [
        // kSecAttrService,  kSecAttrAccount, and kSecClass
        // uniquely identify the item to save in Keychain
        kSecAttrService: service,  // <--- eg "test.com.service"
        kSecAttrAccount: account,
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        // kSecValueData is the item value to save
        kSecValueData: password
    ]
```

see also my `KeyChainClass.swift` at: https://github.com/workingDog/KeychainClass that is entirely based on https://www.advancedswift.com/secure-private-data-keychain-swift/

Also make sure you have set your App.entitlements,

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)test.com.test</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Hint: If you annotate `[CFString:Any]` you can delete all bridge casts, and the dictionary can be bridged directly to `CFDictionary`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll update my answer and my KeychainClass.